# why `ifroom` does not work - android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-menu

hi there I try set `ifroom` in my menu item. you can see in this code I try all possible senario (please see each `showAsAction` item

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_forward"

        android:title="forward"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_forward"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        ></item>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_zoom_in"
        android:title="zoom in"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_zoom_in"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        ></item>



    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:title="home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        ></item>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:title="refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        ></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_zoom_out"
        android:title="zoom out"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_zoom_out"
        showAsAction="ifRoom"
        ></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_back"
        android:title="back"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_back"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        ></item>
</menu>
```

but it just show `action_back` and `action_home` in main page.

I am noob in android studio but I think this error related to width of menu.
(It is not 100% width)

Please see my **main_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_bottom"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar_bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and 
**tool_bar_bottom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

I think the structure is true and values of all `layout_width` is `match_parent` so why `ifroom` do not work for me?

Comment: try `app:showAsAction` instead of `android:showAsAction`

Comment: Thanks but please check my question again! this is not my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android will show menu always if you set "showAsAction" attribute as "always". If you set "ifRoom", that will be displayed only if the actionbar has room to display you menu item, else it will display a overflow icon.

In your case, you are seeing "action_back" because it has "always". then "action_home" becuase there is room for one icon and that is the first item which has "app:showAsAction" attribute. others have "android:showAsAction" attribute. More explanation on this behaviour is below.

> If your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on versions
>   as low as Android 2.1, the showAsAction attribute is not available
>   from the android: namespace. Instead this attribute is provided by the
>   Support Library and you must define your own XML namespace and use
>   that namespace as the attribute prefix. (A custom XML namespace should
>   be based on your app name, but it can be any name you want and is only
>   accessible within the scope of the file in which you declare it.)